# How do you always have delayed job running on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, terminal, rake, delayed-job

I have an app on Heroku running delayed jobs. However at the moment I have to start the job queue running with the terminal command:

```
heroku rake jobs:work
```

...but this means when I shut down my terminal the app's delayed job queue shuts down too.

Is there a way I can get Heroku to just always start and run delayed job in the background when the app starts up? Without having to run the command each time and without having it directly linked to my terminal shell?

Thanks very much.

Edit:

It's on the bamboo stack. Upping workers or running rake jobs:work , the delayed jobs runs for a while, but then the queue seems to just stop getting processed. There are no errors in the delayed jobs queue, the workers just stop processing the jobs. It has to explicitly restarted every 5 or 10 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong rake gem.

The following was causing an issues with rails 3 on Heroku:

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
```

Updating the gem fixed the issues, even though there were not errors in the log:

```
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
```

Answer (score 4):

[From the docs:](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job)

On Heroku's Aspen or Bamboo stack, use `heroku workers 1`

On the Cedar stack, you put this line in your Procfile:

```
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

And then do `heroku scale worker=1`.

Comment: I have an extra worker running all the time, but the jobs don't seem to begin without running the command on the terminal. It's on the bamboo stack.

Answer (score 2):

we use the [workless gem](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) with our heroku stack. it starts worker when the delayed_job queue > 0 and quits the worker when delayed_job queue goes to 0.